# Integrating powers of polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

Is there any way to symbolically integrate, say,
$$\int (2x^2+7)^{10}dx$$
other than to expand the polynomial and apply the power rule? I suspect not, but wanted to make sure there wasn't some integration technique I was forgetting.

Comment: Do you mean like substitution?

Comment: The edit makes substitution a lot less feasible. My recommendation would just be to use the binomial theorem. The actual answer isn't any nicer in practice, but at least it can be written compactly

Comment: @Randall I meant to do write an example where there was not an obvious (to me) substitution. Edited Accordingly.

Comment: If you substitute $x=\sqrt{7/2}\tan u$ then the important part of the integrand becomes $\sec^{12} u$.  Then you can use a reduction formula.

Comment: One could rewrite

$$(2x^2 + 7)^{10} = 2^{10} \left( \sqrt{ x^2 + \left( \sqrt{\frac{7}{2}} \right)^2 } \right)^{20}$$

as well, and perhaps try the substitution

$$x = \sqrt{ \frac 7 2 } \tan \theta$$

Granted, this is quite a bit messier than the binomial theorem, but reduction formulas exist for the resulting integral. (Plus this approach dies hard with higher powers in the parenthetical.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a power of a binomial, The Binomial Theorem works fine. It won't be fast, in the final calculation though.

Consider:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}$$

In your case:

$$\int (2x^2 + 7)^{10}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{10} \binom{10}{k} \int (2x^2)^k 7^{10-k}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{10} \binom{10}{k} 7^{10-k} \int x^{2k}\ \text{d}x$$

The integral is now trivial, giving you

$$\int (2x^2 + 7)^{10}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{10} \binom{10}{k} 7^{10-k} \dfrac{2x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+C$$